# In a Rails MVC project, where should post-query data transforms take place? Model or Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Here's the scenario...

A View needs data to be handed to it in a very specific format/manner (in order to fit nicely into a third-party charting API). When data is extracted from the database, it must be transformed before it meets the View's needs.

According to the principals of MVC, **where should this data transformation take place?**

Options:

- I could ask an action method in the Controller to both extract the data from the database and transform it, before passing it to the View. Or...
- I could instead create a method in the Model that extracts and transforms the data, before passing it to the Controller (who then passes it to the View).

I've opted to stick all of this in a Model method, like so:

```
def self.rating_chart_data
  Film.group(:rating).count.transform_keys{ |key|
    key == 1 ? (key.to_s + " Star") : (key.to_s + " Stars")}
end
```

I don't feel super confident about this decision though. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

A controller is responsible for handling the incoming request and transferring the processed data to the view. All the data processing must be done at the model level.
If you see your models becoming fat overtime or if there's a reusable code component that you can use across the app then that code needs to be placed inside a module/concern/services.
However, there are view helpers as well that are intended to remove clutter from your views and return processed data.

Here's a [useful article](https://medium.com/kkempin/facade-design-pattern-in-ruby-on-rails-710aa88326f) that'll help you understand how to organize your code structure and follow the MVC pattern correctly.
Hope that helps.